# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am following along the tutorial Ruby on Rail 3 Essential Training from Lynda.com. I am having a difficult time creating an Active Record Entry. This is the error I get in my console.

```
1.9.3p125 :007 > user = User.new(:first_name => "Mike", :last_name => "Jones")
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: first_name, last_name
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
    from (irb):7:in `new'
    from (irb):7
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>`
```

This is what I have in my Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name
end
```

What am I doing wrong. I have rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to restart the console. If you have created the model for user after the console was launched, you should restart it.

Comment: reload! in the console should reload the console so you don't have to restart it

Answer (score 10):

From what I know that lynda course was developed on rails3 and in rails 3.2.3 there is no mass assignment by default. You have to go your model and add attr_accessible :name, :position, :visible. Basically you have to add every attribute you want to mass assign.

Answer (score 2):

Without any precautions Mass-assignment allows attackers to set any database column’s value, hence it has been disabled by default.

```
def signup
  params[:user] # => {:name => “ow3ned”, :admin => true}
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
end
```

The detailed description is in the [Ruby On Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Answer (score 2):

I just added the attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :username line to the models file.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was too following along the tutorial Ruby on Rail 3 Essential Training from Lynda.com, if anybody had the same problem here is what worked for me,

Turn off the security setting. Open config/application.rb and change config.active_record.whitelist_attributes to false instead of true. This makes your app a little less secure, but allows you to quickly move forward with the tutorial.
this is from: http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-on-Rails-3-tutorials/essential-training/55960-2/faqs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put `attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name` in the User model and not in the controller.